# Variable substitution like usual maths

Tags: replacement, variable-definitions, language-design

So... I'm trying to get some simplifications on equations using own defined variables, but the tries I gave didn't result on what I wanted.

The problem: I have 2 variables defined as:

```
x = (z[1, 2] z[3, 4])/(z[1, 3] z[2, 4])

k = (z[1, 3] z[2, 4])/(z[1, 2] z[2, 3] z[3, 4] z[4, 1])
```

Where

```
z[a_,b_] := z[a] - z[b]
```

And i'm trying the result:

```
k = 1/(x z[2,3]z[4,1])
```

My tries:

```
Simplify[Eliminate[{k == (
    z[1, 3] z[2, 4])/(z[1, 2] z[2, 3] z[3, 4] z[4, 1]), 
   x == (z[1, 2] z[3, 4])/(z[1, 3] z[2, 4])}, {z[1, 2], z[2, 4], 
   z[3, 4], z[1, 3]}]]
```

and

```
k /. (z[1, 2] z[3, 4])/(z[1, 3] z[2, 4]) -> x (* into this one I only defined k before*)
```

I searched  and so, but either I got something that I already  tried or something incredible hard. So I don't know if I got something wrong or is really hard to get substitutions.

**EDIT 1**

So, this is just an example of how I would like the program to work not just using to print the answer I want. I want him to simplify the expression using my definitions. In the second try I got him to substitute if was only one term(Like z[1,2]) so I'm start to thinking that way don't substitute in a mathematical way.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[x, k, z]
With[{
   k = (z[1, 3] z[2, 4])/(z[1, 2] z[2, 3] z[3, 4] z[4, 1]),
   x = (z[1, 2] z[3, 4])/(z[1, 3] z[2, 4])
   },
  k x
  ]/x
```